# Выполнение любого действия, при условии, что выполнены 2 других. С помощью событий

Tags: c#, winforms

Друзья, такая задача. Есть форма на которой два элемента `textBox` и 1 элемент `button`. Изначально элемент `button` не активен. Активным он должен стать только тогда, когда в элементах `textBox` появится хоть 1 символ. Я сделал таким вот образом, с помощью двух флажков.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool tb1 = false;
    bool tb2 = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb1 = true;
        if ((tb1 == true) && tb2 == true)
            button1.Enabled = true;            
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb2 = true;
        if ((tb1 == true) && tb2 == true)
            button1.Enabled = true;  
    }
}
```

Но уверен, что с помощью делегатов и событий эту задачу можно решить куда красивее, но я не разобрался как. Буду признателен, если кто-то подскажет.

Comment: Твое событие это ввод символа в любое из полей. Ставишь проверку на число символов в каждом из них. Как только оно стало больше нуля в каждом из них вызывай что тебе нужно. ИМХО так. Может ошибаюсь.

Comment: а чем вас текущее не устраивает? все довольно логично, разве что можно немного сократить заменив `(tb1 == true) && tb2 == true` на `tb1 && tb2`, логические переменные сами по себе могут использоваться в условиях.